# Subharmonic function on a twice punctured complex plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, harmonic-functions

is the twice punctured complex plane parabolic or hyperbolic? In this sense: does $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$ admit a nonconstant, negative, subharmonic function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A subharmonic function which is bounded from above near a polar set automatically extends through it. 
Therefore, any negative subharmonic function on $\mathbb C \setminus\{0,1\}$ induces a negative subharmonic function on $\mathbb C$, and by Liouville theorem, it must be constant.

So the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 2):

The $j$-invariant in the theory of elliptic curves is a covering map from the upper half plane to the complex plane punctured at $0$ and $1$. See Koblitz, **Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms**.

Comment: I don't think you mean the $j$-invariant (which does take both values $0$ and $1$) but rather a modular function for $\Gamma_0(4)$.